# IE11 with JAWS not correctly reading aria-pressed

Tags: accessibility, wai-aria, jaws-screen-reader

I am relatively new to working with JAWS and trying to fine tune some discrepancies between Firefox and IE when working with it.

Currently, I have a crystal reports popup window that has two toggles, for example, one is for find. That once it's triggered, the user can type their search string. This div has an `aria-role="button"`as well as an `aria-pressed="true/false"` value. However, in IE11, JAWS is not reading back whether the button is pressed or not like Firefox does.

Any insight? Has anybody else hit this issue?

```
<div tabindex="0" 
 title="Find"
 class="someClassName"
 id="someID"
 role="button" aria-pressed="false">...img...</div>
```

*Note: I've replaced the lengthy classes and auto-generated ID.*

Answer (score 1):

It might be a JAWS bug. However, basically it is not good to do things like `<div role="button">`:

> Do not do this:
>
> `<h1 role=button>heading button</h1>`
>
> Do this:
>
> `<h1><button>heading button</button></h1>`

© Www Consortium, The second rule of ARIA use from [here](https://www.w3.org/TR/aria-in-html/).

So, in your case I'd use a `<button>` rather than a `<div>`.
Actually, the first rule of ARIA use also applies and maybe is even more appropriate here:

> If you can use a native HTML element [HTML 5.1] or attribute with the semantics and behavior you require already built in, instead of re-purposing an element and adding  an ARIA role, state or property
>   to make it accessible, then do so.

Comment: Thank you for some clarity. Unfortunately, with this window being generated by Crystal Reports I don't believe we have access to update the markup. I will poke around and see what I can find but this may be, like you said, a JAWS issue based on the markup. Thank you.

Comment: Hm. I am not experiencing this issue with JAWS 17. I'm using a private beta however, so I might be not a good example there. Anyway, try [this](http://oire.kissr.com/aria-pressed.html) tiny page I've just prepared based on your input data. What do you see there?